# Skip incompatible kernels when configuring virtualbox-dkms

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualbox, dkms

I have a "mainline" unsigned kernel (5.9.7, from the mainline PPA) and some other regular kernels from Focal. Trying to install virtualbox, it attempts to build dkms for 5.9.7, fails without trying the other kernels, and helpfully leaves virtualbox unconfigured. How do I get apt to ignore failures, or not even try, for some kernels?

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.9.7-050907-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.9.7-050907-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
 virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
  Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```